# GetTitleBarInfo function doesn't return values

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm using the `GetTitleBarInfo` function in this way

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  TitleInfo       : TTitleBarInfo;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@TitleInfo, SizeOf(TitleInfo));
  GetTitleBarInfo(Handle, TitleInfo);
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(TitleInfo.rcTitleBar.Left));
end;
```

But none of the GetTitleBarInfo return values (all the values are zero), what I'm missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation of the [`GetTitleBarInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function states that you must set the cbSize member to 
sizeof(TTitleBarInfo) before calling this function, also you must check the boolean result returned by the function.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  TitleInfo       : TTitleBarInfo;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@TitleInfo, SizeOf(TitleInfo));
  TitleInfo.cbSize:=SizeOf(TitleInfo);
  if GetTitleBarInfo(Handle, TitleInfo) then
   ShowMessage(IntToStr(TitleInfo.rcTitleBar.Left));
end;
```

Comment: Which you would have been able to catch if you had been checking the return value of `GetTitleBarInfo()`, as it would have been returning `FALSE`.